# How to convert int to byte[] in C# without using System helper functions?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, bit-shift

To convert an int to a byte[], I would normally use `BitConverter`, but I'm currently working within a framework called UdonSharp that restricts access to most `System` methods, so I'm unable to use that helper function. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
private byte[] GetBytes(int target)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    bytes[0] = (byte)(target >> 24);
    bytes[1] = (byte)(target >> 16);
    bytes[2] = (byte)(target >> 8);
    bytes[3] = (byte)target;
    return bytes;
}
```

It works for the most part, but the problem is that it breaks when `target` is greater than 255, throwing an exception `Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.`. I imagine this is because on the final part `bytes[3] = (byte)target;` it is trying to convert a value greater than 255 directly to an int. But I just want it to convert the final 8 bits of the int to the final byte, not the whole thing. How can I accomplish that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to mask off the bits you don't need: `bytes[3] = (byte)(target & 0xFF)` etc

Comment: If the problem is a problem of masking, then he has to mask everyone of the four bytes... And then I suggest you try with `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue` just to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, all results should be % 256 before the typecast. (or bitmask like mentioned in other comment)

Comment: Side note: there's actually a very good reason to avoid `BitConverter` here, even when it is available - or at least treat it with caution; `BitConverter` is CPU-endian, meaning it won't always produce the same output on all devices; the shift+mask approach, however, is endian-independent and will work the same anywhere. In modern .NET there's a `BinaryPrimitives` type that largely replaces `BitConverter`; it deals in spans, and has endian-specific methods.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you commenters! This did the trick:

```
private byte[] Int32ToBytes(int inputInt32)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    bytes[0] = (byte)((inputInt32 >> 24) % 256);
    bytes[1] = (byte)((inputInt32 >> 16) % 256);
    bytes[2] = (byte)((inputInt32 >> 8) % 256);
    bytes[3] = (byte)(inputInt32 % 256);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Note that `& 0xFF` is semantically identical and more commonly used in masking; which is *faster* is something you'd need to benchmark (personally, I'd wager the `&` out-performs the `%`, but I wouldn't wager my house). Or alternatively: just use `unchecked`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're compiling in `checked` mode; which is *fine* (albeit unusual), but sometimes you *don't want that*, so:

```cs
private byte[] GetBytes(int target)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    unchecked
    {
        bytes[0] = (byte)(target >> 24);
        bytes[1] = (byte)(target >> 16);
        bytes[2] = (byte)(target >> 8);
        bytes[3] = (byte)target;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Also, note that allocating an array each time is *really* expensive; it is usually a better idea to pass *in* a buffer to write to.